# What are they saying to my son?

Tags: español-neutral, identificación-de-término

My son is trying out for soccer team. All but 3 of the 40+ students speak Spanish as their primary language. They keep calling my son something. He said it sounds like me-gay. I am not entirely sure how to spell it in Spanish.

What are they calling him?

Comment: "He said it sounds like me-gay" Maybe it is Miguel?

Comment: No. Many of the hispanic boys called only the 3 white kids trying out. I dont know if ir was like some sort of instruction or if they were calling them a name. He said it sounded like me-gay.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit in which country the other players are from, of you know that, in case this is a regional usage?

Comment: My advice would actually be visiting the [parenting stack](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/). First look for questions related to this problem. If you can't find anything post your own question. Maybe you should actually go to one of the soccer session and see first hand how those interactions are and/or talk to the coach(es) there. Try to befriend other Spanish-speaking adults in there, so you have help with the language. It doesn't matter what names they are calling, but there's a problem _if_ they are aggressive to a team mate or _if_ there's bulling or picking on somebody. Good luck

Comment: Why would they call him "Miguel"? It it's his name, it would be obvious enough. If it isn't, there's no reason to call him by a random name.

Comment: As you can see, folks here are eager to help you.  But this just isn't enough information.  You don't have to supply *all* of the following, but if you could supply *some* of these, it might give us enough to be able to solve the puzzle.  Your son's age, as mentioned, countries the other players are from, recording of the word (a cell phone could be used for making the recording), the context in which they say the word, your son's first name (for example, if it's Mike, they might be saying "Miguel"), whether they call anyone else the same thing.  You or your son could ask someone...

Comment: As you can see, folks here are eager to help you.  But this just isn't enough information.  You don't have to supply *all* of the following, but if you could supply *some* of these, it might give us enough to be able to solve the puzzle.  Your son's age, as mentioned, countries the other players are from, recording of the word (a cell phone could be used for making the recording), the context in which they say the word, your son's first name (for example, if it's Mike, they might be saying "Miguel"), whether they call anyone else the same thing.  You or your son could ask someone...

Comment: ... to write it down.  It's very unlikely that none of the players does not understand that level of basic English.  Can you arrive a little early to the end of practice one day, and strike up a conversation with one of the other parents?

Comment: @walen - (Sure, if he's mature enough and feels comfortable doing so.)

Answer (score 2):

"Amigo" (friend) sounds to some extent like "me gay". It is one of the very few things that hand those `m` and `g`m sounds similar to waht you describe and would be used in such context. One could try to convey its pronunciation as "aa-m-EE-g-oh", "uh-mee-goh" or "ah-mee-gaw". Judge for yourself [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dS7BfaPsxpY) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVEqO9R-R-w). Be aware that pronunciation can vary according to the country of origin of those kids, among other things.

"Amigo" and "me-gay" are completely different to me (a native Spanish speaker), but depending on how they say it, your own listening skills (or those of whoever described the word to you) and other nuances (like the problem of how to describe what you heard in written form on the Internet), it might be the word you are looking for.